# Can't get async to work in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to run the following code block from the official [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html):

```
  async function getMoviesFromApi() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json');
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      return responseJson.movies;
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

When I try running this I get the error:

```
"Unexpected token, expected ( (31:17)"
```

If I remove the `function` keyword, it works fine.

What difference does it make if I use the function keyword or not? Is it because I am using it in a class? Where in the documentation does it indicate this? Is it in the react-native documentation or the JavaScript documentation? I cannot seem to find it either place, though I could be searching for the wrong thing.

I am using react-native: 0.38.0 (with react-native-cli: 1.2.0)

Comment: What version of JS is it? [It works in Babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=latest&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=async%20function%20getMoviesFromApi()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20try%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20response%20%3D%20await%20fetch('https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.github.io%2Freact-native%2Fmovies.json')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20responseJson%20%3D%20await%20response.json()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20responseJson.movies%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20catch(error)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.error(error)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&playground=true).

Answer (score 3):

> Is it because I am using it in a class?

Probably. The syntax for declaring methods in a class is

```
class Foo {
  method() {}
}
```

**not**

```
class Foo {
  function method() {}
}
```

Hence an async method is declared as

```
class Foo {
  async method() {}
}
```

> Where in the documentation does it indicate this? Is it in the react-native documentation or the JavaScript documentation?

It's JavaScript. React is a framework/library, not a language. All the syntax you are using is JavaScript (except JSX of course, but that's not specific to React either).

See the [MDN documentation about classe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)s.